# How to model a wavy chair?

Tags: modeling

How can I make a wavy chair like this? [image]

Comment: Do either answers posted answer your question, @user34085?

Answer (score 6):

A curve with a curve bevel object would produce this shape with lots of control.

The bevel object is the cutaway side view of a slice of the chair. The chair curve is the overall shape of the chair.

[image: chair made with curve bevel object]

[image]

Comment: Use [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for blend file uploads. Not only is the site you linked to unfarmiliar, but your link also doesn't work at all.

Comment: @X-27 Fixed! I was trying to figure out how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just did this super quick but this should get you going in the right direction.

[image]

Its just a procedural wave texture. Of course you would want to add fresnel and glossy shader but hope this helps a little.

Just play with the color Ramp and Math node for different looks.

Comment: As far as I can see it, the waves are not circular, and instead of the roughness you probably want to modify the normals or the displacement - the waves are real bumps in the photo. Otherwise it is a great idea to do it with a procedural texture!

Comment: @ibalazscs You are correct. I have corrected my node setup.